# How to create local group policy object from domain GPO

Tags: windows

I need to know how I can create and deploy a local group policy with settings that exist in my domain GPO. I know local GPO only supports a subset of what domain GP does and I think that's where the problem exists. The settings I need to apply are contained within the Computer Config -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> security Settings -> **system services**, **Wireless Network (802.11) Policies**, and **Wired Network (802.3) Policies**. These three options do not exist in either XP or 7 local GPO.
 I have investigated using secedit and security templates from the SCA snap-in but it doesn't appear that they contain these settings either.
So the question is simple, how can I apply the settings that are already configured in a domain GPO to a local GPO?

Comment: I don't quite follow... if It's already applied in a domain GPO then it doesn't need to be applied in a local GPO because the domain GPO gets applied.

Comment: Right. The problem is that I am using a domain policy to apply dot1x settings. Occasionally I have a client that fails to authenticate for some reason (network issue, acs down, etc) and when the client is disconnected from the domain, the domain policy does not get applied. When this happens, the authentication settings on the NIC change resulting in the workstation never being able to reauthenticate correctly again. I have to manually force-authorize the port, reboot to get the domain policy then put the port back to auto.

Comment: Ahhh okay. That makes sense. Have you tried exporting the GPO and importing on the local machine itself?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by export/import?

Comment: Sorry if that comment sounded ignorant but I've been trying to figure out how to do just that. I can't seem to find a way to "export" a group policy object. I even tried manually copying the policy files from the sysvol share to the %systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy folder but the files in the sysvol share didn't contain any settings oddly.

Comment: This question belongs on [sf].

Comment: I have a specific dot1x question there. I've started a bounty because I've had minimal responses. Considering group policies, security templates, etc. I thought I might have better luck here in that regard. Please leave it for a couple days to prove me wrong. I really need an answer

Comment: @PaulAckerman This question is not a security question, it's an application issue.  Those belong on [sf], but you *may* be able to pass it off on [su].  Either of those sites have many more users and traffic, and it's *much* more likely to get an appropriate answer (and be useful to the rest of the community) there.

Answer (score 2):

(This old question was bumped to the homepage by Community and hasn't yet been answered.)

In general: if a setting doesn't exist in Local Group Policy Editor, it cannot be imported.

The proposed solution for the original problem was trying to export GPO from a domain and import it to the Local Group Policy. Instead, it was correct that **these settings are domain specific**, which means it wouldn't help to export/import them under these circumstances.

While it is possible to export domain specific settings from one domain and import them to another domain using [Migration Tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771452(v=ws.11).aspx) *to reference users, groups, computers, and UNC paths in the source GPO to new values in the destination GPO*, it is not possible to import such settings to Local GP.

An TechNet Community Support answer on [Applying Domain GPO to standalone machines](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/b4ad60e4-97cc-4a49-953e-c01bfc7c7a0e/applying-domain-gpo-to-standalone-machines) lists:

> Following items contain security principals and can be modified using
>   a migration table, these domain GPOs may not available in local
>   policy:
>
> - Security policy settings of the following types:
>
>   - User rights assignment
>   - Restricted groups
>   - System services
>   - File system
>   - Registry
> - Advanced folder redirection settings
> - The GPO DACL, if it is preserved during a copy operation
> - The DACL on software installation objects, which is only 
>     preserved if the option to copy the GPO DACL is specified

The *Wireless Network (802.11) Policies* and *Wired Network (802.3) Policies* from the question are both under *System services* from the list above.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the Group Policy Management Console to export the GPO as an inf and then move it to the target machine(s)

Comment: I see where I can create a "backup" within GPMC but this just creates a copy of what's in the sysvol share. A folder with the UID of the gpo with adm, machine and user inside - none of my settings. How do I create an inf from the GPO with GPMC??